# Retrieve ModelMap value from Spring MVC controller to jquery in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, spring, spring-mvc

I am doing project in Spring 4.0.2. In Spring MVC controller I have used ModelMap attributes and I want to retrieve the same in jquery in html file.

My Servlet code

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(ModelMap model,@ModelAttribute TravelSearchDTO travelSearchForm, HttpServletRequest request) {
    Integer maxSeatSelection = dto.getMaxSeats();
    model.addAttribute("maxSeatNo",maxSeatSelection);       
    String returnText = "static/html/search";
    return returnText;
}
```

My jquery code in search.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var ss = '${maxSeatNo}'; 
alert(ss);
</script>
```

No alert for ss value appeared. Also I am in great doubt that whether I need to use the variable in script declaration or in document.ready function. Please clarify above doubts to access the Modelmap value in html.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `var ss = "${maxSeatNo}";`
This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
var ss = [[${maxSeatNo}]];
```